# Ruby: 'new' without a class

Tags: ruby

My understanding of Ruby was that the 'new' keyword was always combined with a class name to create a new instance of a class. In the code below, found at https://gist.github.com/e9c0da1a6e92dd12cbc7, which was submitted as a solution to a  Ruby Programming Challenge for Newbies contest, the author uses the 'new' keyword three times without instantiating a class.

In one case, new(0,0) is assigned to a constant CLOSED. In another case, new(open,close) is a return value from a function. Why do it this way? What is 'new' doing when it's used this way? what is it creating?

```
class OpenHours

    attr_reader :open, :close

    def initialize(open, close)
      @open, @close = open, close
    end

    def duration
      @duration ||= @open < @close ? @close - @open : 0
    end

    CLOSED = new(0, 0)                #first new


    def self.parse(open, close)
      open  = Time.parse(open)
      close = Time.parse(close)


      open  = TimeUtils::seconds_from_midnight(open)
      close = TimeUtils::seconds_from_midnight(close)


      new(open, close)                        #second new

    end

    def offset(seconds)
      self.class.new([@open, seconds].max, @close)     #third new
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the receiver is `self`, the receiver can be omitted. The first two `new` calls that you are questioning are called within the context of `OpenHours`, which means that `self` is set to `OpenHours`. Therefore `new` without the explicit receiver is equivalent to `self.new` and `OpenHours.new`. In your third example, the context is an instance of `OpenHours`. `self` refers to that instance, and `self.class` refers to `OpenHours`, so `self.class.new` is equivalent to `OpenHours.new`. In all cases, the created object is an instance of `OpenHours`.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, `new` is *not* an operator or keyword. It is an instance method of `Class` instances. For example, the object `OpenHours` is a class, and therefore is an instance of `Class`, and therefore has an instance method `new`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenHours::CLOSED is an instance of OpenHours

```
irb(main):034:0> OpenHours::CLOSED
=> #<OpenHours:0x3ee2e85d @open=0, @close=0>
irb(main):035:0> OpenHours::CLOSED.class
=> OpenHours
```

To be honest, I don't know what they're doing here. I think it's bad code.

**Reply to comment**: If you do `foo = OpenHours.parse(open, close)`, then the instance will be assigned to `foo`

Comment: so is the self.parse method returning an instance new(open, close)   of OpenHours?   Shouldn't it be assigned to something?